# Fullscreen link with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, fullscreen

I have a responsive index page with only a background-image as content. When you click, wherever in the page, there must be a link to the homepage.

Second, it would be nice also that instead of a simple pointer, the visitor sees a link icon (don't know what the 'hand' is called) over the whole page, so he immediately knows that everything on the whole page is clickable.

Searched a lot over the internet, perhaps my question is too simple, cannot find an answer anywhere, not even in tutorials.

Here is what I already figured out with what I know. It's incomplete and surely the third line is not correct, I don't know the syntax.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("body").on("click", function(){
    $(this).a href 'home.html'();
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: To show a hand mouse pointer you need to add the css property 'cursor: pointer' in your body.

Comment: For your first problem, break it down into pieces. The click event function will accept a parameter `e` which is an object, and that might contain mouse co-ordinates. You might be able to use that to reposition a div containing a link at a specific location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to go to a specific url do `window.location.href` in your `.click()` function

to make the cursor a hand do `cursor: pointer;` in your css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without JavaScript.

Use an anchor (no need for cursor styling) and use CSS to have it fill the entire window.

Note: This example also allows for a text fallback if CSS is disabled.

```css
.full-page {
        background:url("http://placehold.it/50x50") repeat;
  
        /* full page link */
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        position:fixed;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        
        /* hide text */
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<a class="full-page" href="/home.html">Click to go home</a>
```